# iOS Device Test Mode and old iOS development

Tags: ios

When I was signing up for development program, then in the agreement, I saw a clause which basically stated that if a pre-release software is installed on any device, then that device will be put in test mode. So, what exactly is the limitation of a test mode as compared to a device which is in "normal" mode? Also, if I install iOS7 in a device (after iOS 7 has been released), then will the device be considered to be in a test mode if I test my application on it ?

Moreover, if I submit an application which runs on iOS 6 after iOS 7 has been launched, then can that be considered grounds for app rejection ? I will develop app for iOS 7 also. However, that will take some time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no practical difference once you start using a device for development. I use my personal iPhone for most of my testing; it has no effect whatsoever on the utility of the phone.

On your second question: your app will NOT be rejected simply for supporting iOS 6, or any older version of iOS. Apple wants you to write apps that support iOS 7, of course, but they absolutely will not reject an app for supporting older versions; that would be crazy.

If your app actually failed to work on iOS 7 (once it's released), then obviously that would be a different matter.

Comment: So, the same app should work on both iOS6 and iOS7 ? I thought that we can give separate apps for iOS6 and iOS7

Comment: The same binary needs to support both OSes: you can't submit separate apps to the App Store for 6 and 7. Take a look at the iOS 7 UI Transition Guide on developer.apple.com for more info.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no limitation in "test mode".
If your application is developed for iOS 6, then it should still work on iOS 7 as well, but with the iOS 6 look & feel. However, it is always best to test it on a real device with iOS 7, of course.